# How to retrieve data from deployd to use in android application?

Tags: android, deployd

I am trying to discover deployd, and i have created a simple table for data storage. The table is stored at

```
http://localhost:2403/table
```

as a JSONArray. I can get the data with the following code:

```
private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
      sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

  public static JSONArray readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
    try {
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
      String jsonText = readAll(rd);
      JSONArray json = new JSONArray(jsonText);
      return json;
    } finally {
      is.close();
    }
  }

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {
    JSONArray obj = readJsonFromUrl("http://localhost:2403/table");     

}
```

My question is, this data is stored in the localhost. Let's say, i want to use this database  in my android application. Then obviously i cannot use

```
JSONArray obj = readJsonFromUrl("http://localhost:2403/table")
```

to get the json array. So, how can i get it? I looked at the documentation and could not find anything. What link should i use instead of local host:2403/table?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you develop, you can use the ip of the machine where you run Deployd like:
`http://192.168.0.42:2403/table`

(192.168.0.42 has to be replaced by the IP of your local machine).

If you want to use your backend in the real world, you'll have to deploy it somewhere.
Heroku for example. Here's some code to do that:
https://gist.github.com/facultymatt/5373247

Comment: I can access the data using http://192.168.2.5:2403/my-objects however, only when we are connected to the same wifi. Is any reason I cant connect from an external network (my mobile using mobile data)?